# Questions about the glht function for planned comparison

Tags: r, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, contrasts

I have a nested model with the following effects

- fixed: treatments
- random: experiment_date

I used `lme()` to model the data

```
mod1 <- lme(N_cells ~treatments-1, random=~1|experiment_date, method='ML')
```

Then I want to compare all the other treatments to the control (included in
the "treatments" in `mod1`). After a fair amount of searching around, I
decided to use `glht()` from the [multcomp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/index.html) package (any other suggestions?).

```
lvl.treatments=table(treatments)
K = contrMat(lvl.treatments,type='Dunnett',base=1)
mc<-glht(mod1, linfct=mcp(treatments=K),alternative='greater')
```

But I got the following error:

> Error in contr.treatment(n = 0L) :   not enough degrees of freedom to
>   define contrasts

I tried to extract the df parameter using `modelparm()`, but the function
couldn't be applied to lme

> Error in UseMethod("modelparm") :   no applicable method for
>   'modelparm' applied to an object of class "lme"

The degree of freedom of the fixed effect was 194. I tried to specify the
number in `glht()`, but got the same error as "not enough degrees of freedom to
define contrasts".

Does anyone know what's happening and how I could possibly solve the
problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If your treatments are factors (and not ordered factors), you could add the intercept into the model (i.e. remove the "-1") and just do `summary(mod1)`

The default contrasts, as set in options, is to use contr.treatment for factors.  This sounds like what you want.  contr.treatment means that each coefficient represents a comparison of that level with level 1 (omitting level 1 itself).

```
# view default contrasts in options
options("contrasts")
#$contrasts
#        unordered           ordered 
#"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly"
```

When you do `summary(mod1)`, the first level will not be labelled, but all the other levels will be in comparison to it.

If your control condition is not your first level, you need to use `factor()` with a levels argument or `relevel()` to make it first.

Comment: Thank you, MattBagg. This makes a lot sense now. I was wondering if there is a way to specify the alternative hypothesis, e.g., my testing treatment is lower than the control. I have looked through the help documents of contr.treatment etc, but I did not find anything useful.

Comment: I would probably just extract the t- or p- value and calculate that myself. For example,  `summary(mod1)$tTable[,"p-value"]`  The t-value would remain the same and the one-tailed p-value is either 0.5*(two-tailed p-value) or 1-0.5*(two-tailed p-value) depending on the direction.